# Who said "of them which thou gavest me have I lost none"?

Tags: john, prophecy

In John 18:9, Jesus (or John) says:

> That the saying might be fulfilled, which he spake, Of them which thou gavest me have I lost none.

However, I couldn't find what scriptures is being quoted here. I checked every verse in the Bible for the words loss/lose/lost and came up with nothing.  (there were only 32 search hits).

So is this a quote of some scripture that is not in the Bible?

Comment: It looks to me like the words are Jesus'. [The NIV places quotes and makes this more clear.](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+18&version=NIV)

Comment: John 17:12.................

Comment: The simplest explanation is that there were 'scriptures' or 'oral traditions' that we are no longer familiar with or that is no longer part of Christianity. The answer in Hermeneutics (Psalm 41: 9) takes a bit of imagination - the Psalm is about being sick, and maybe only those that have been really sick will understand that 'best friends' are not always 'friends' when one is sick.